# Is there a way in python to dynamically assign variable names?

Tags: python

First question here, sorry if I make any mistakes.

I'm learning python and pandas dataframes. I have a very large dataframe that has data for many years and I'd like to separate it in diferent dataframes filtered by years.

Say for instance that for `df_general` there are 10 years. Is there some way that I can call a `for` loop that dinamically assign the years to the variable names? I already have a function `sliceDataframeByYear` ready.

Basically what I want do is something like this

```
    for i in range(10):
        filteredDataframe = sliceDataframeByYear(df_general,i)
        dataframeYear + i = filteredDataframe
```

But when I run this I'd like to have `dataframeYear + i` as a the new object name, so after running something similar to that I'd be able to call say `dataframeYear0`, `dataframeYear1` and so on directly.

Currently I have to do something like this:

```
    dfYear2021 = sliceDataframeByYear(df_general,2021)
    dfYear2020 = sliceDataframeByYear(df_general,2021)
    dfYear2019 = sliceDataframeByYear(df_general,2019)
```

My idea is to have a for loop that automatically create those variables with the name and corresponding data.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: I think a *dictionary* would be a better choice.

Comment: What do you plan to do by creating dataframes with different variable names? Are you going to save them into different files?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, someone refered to an answer that suggested that, I'll try that out.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Yes, I will run some code to generate a report and save the original dataset too. I'll try the dictionary approach tho. Thanks!